# Mongodb GeoSpatial Query with NodeJs (Haversine formula)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geolocation, geospatial

I have a collection where I am storing 2 locations for every entry.  These locations are 
the starting point and destination point for a particular route. I know I can write the following query to find the nearby places to query for a particular location:

```
exports.nearby = function(req, res){
db.testpool.find({
    fromLoc: {
        $near: [28.423168, 77.045639],
        $maxDistance: 1
    },

}).toArray(function(err, doc){
    res.send(doc);
    if(err)
        console.log(err+'');
    else
    {
        res.send(doc+'');
    }});
```

But i dont know the query which i should make in order to find the relevant routes which 
not only match fromLoc but also the toLoc and i keep getting error When i do something like this :-

```
exports.nearby = function(req, res){
db.testpool.find({
    fromLoc: {
        $near: [28.423168, 77.045639],
        $maxDistance: 1
    },
    toLoc: {
        $near: [28.649573, 77.125284],
        $maxDistance: 1
    }
}).toArray(function(err, doc){
    res.send(doc);
    if(err)
        console.log(err+'');
    else
    {
        res.send(doc+'');
    }
});
```

So basically I want to find out the most relevant car pools entered by users which will have 
2 locations per entry, e.g. starting location and destination location.

Answer (score 0):

Rigth now you can't have more than one geospatial index per collection*. If you want two indexes you will need at least two differents collections. MongoDB does not have joins but you can create fields that points to another document elsewhere. Those are called [DBRefs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) and are least powerful than proper joins but can be used for similar purposes. There are strategies supported by those "pseudo-joins" in drivers of node.js like the [mongoose's populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

You will not be able to do what you want with a simple query at least until mongoDB supports multiples geospatial indexes. You will need to code it.

For example, we can have two collections. One with the routes and the other ones with locations. The one with the locations is similar to this:

```
{
   "geo": [1,2],
   "origin": [/*dbrefs array*/],
   "destination": [/*dbrefs array*/]
}
```

Then we make two queries, one searching places near to the origin, the other one with places near the destinations. When we already have the result of both queries we do the [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) of the origin field of the first query with the destination field of the second one. To compare two objects you can use [deepEqual in the assert library](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_deepequal_actual_expected_message):

```
var intersection = originField.filter(function(origin){
    for(var k in destinationField){
        if(deepEqual(destinationField[k],origin)){
            return true;
        };
    };

    return false;
})
```

We have the DBRefs of the desired routes that contains it's collection ant `_id` so now we only needs to query those routes. Do it in a row with [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

Hope this helps.

*Check issue [2331](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2331) in mongodb's jira.